# Bosun send alert specifc data via json post body

Tags: bosun

When using `Bosun` you can send a `HTTP POST` request using an alert notification with a specified json body like so:

```
post = myurl
body = {"foo": "bar"}
```

I have an external application which listens to `myurl` and sends and email based on the context of the post body. Is there a way to generically template the post body to represent the triggered alert details.

Ideally something like this (syntax is just for example purposes):

```
 post = myurl
 body = {"body": "Alert.name, Alert.host, ..."}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is is to use a `post` *action* within the definition of the `notification`. You can also override the default post body by using the `body` directive within the notification. You can then use the `json` template function and the `contentType` to set it to JSON.

Two examples follow, from the [notification documentation](http://bosun.org/configuration.html#notification). In particular, I think the second example is what you are after.

```
# post to a slack.com chatroom 
notification slack{
    post = https://company.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=TOKEN
    body = payload={"username": "bosun", "text": {{.|json}}, "icon_url": "http://stackexchange.github.io/bosun/public/bosun-logo-mark.svg"} 
}

#post json
notification json{
    post = https://someurl.com/submit
    body = {"text": {{.|json}}, apiKey="2847abc23"}
    contentType = application/json
}
```

Comment: When it comes to the generic information in the body. I believe the same template variables you see exposed at the bottom of the config test page should be available to the body, for example `{{.Alert.Name}}`

Comment: In a notification, the context of `{{.}}` is the rendered subject from the alert's template. You could certainly make a template with `subject = {{.|json}}`, but that would be a little odd. This may be the best case I have seen yet for merging [#1102](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/pull/1101)